# how can I identify the thread-id in peach function in Q

Tags: kdb

Is there a way to identify threadId (or some other unique identifier) when executing a function within peach? It will be useful for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Aaron Davies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/428843/aaron-davies) wrote a simple shared lib around the [`gettid`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettid.2.html) call in linux, which provides the current thread id. The code and example usage is available in the contributed code section of `code.kx.com` (see [here](http://code.kx.com/wsvn/code/contrib/adavies/gettid/))

If you're running on windows, should be straight forward to modify to work with [`GetCurrentThreadId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683183(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: thanks. will give it try but looks like it should work.

Comment: The library is now available here: https://github.com/adavies42/qist/tree/master/gettid